# Opencv Python resize with one constant

Tags: python, resize, dimension, opencv

I want to resize my image with given one edge's new length by using `cv2.resize()` method.

For example my image has dimension 300x400, and I want to increase my height from 400 to 500 but I should write only one edge's new size(just 500), the other edge should automatically be increased. What is sequence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you are asking for cv2.resize only, but you could use the [imutils](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils) library which does some of the ratio code for you.

```
import imutils
resized = imutils.resize(img, width=newwidth)
```

Inside imutils:

```
dim = None
(h, w) = image.shape[:2]

# check to see if the width is None
if width is None:
    # calculate the ratio of the height and construct the
    # dimensions
    r = height / float(h)
    dim = (int(w * r), height)

# otherwise, the height is None
else:
    # calculate the ratio of the width and construct the
    # dimensions
    r = width / float(w)
    dim = (width, int(h * r))

# resize the image
resized = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=inter)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can resize with the `fx` and `fy` parameters of the `resize` function.

```py
img = cv2.resize(img, (0,0), fx=500/400, fy=500/400)
```